# How can I add a proper image signature to a php mail() message?

Tags: php

I am trying to attach a "signature" with a company logo to the bottom of a message that is sent when the mail() function is called.
Here is the HTML/PHP that I have:

```
$message = '<html>
            <body>'
                . $_POST['message'] .
                '<BR><HR><BR>
                <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.gif">
            </body>
            </html>';
```

When you click on the email that is sent to gmail for example, a dialog comes up and says

`Images are not displayed. Display images below - Always display images from person@mysite.com`

I would like for the signature image to just display without having to click one of the options given in the dialog. Email signatures from others display without that dialog showing up. Is there a way for me to do the same?

It is just very annoying if a user has to click on that option every time to display my signature.

Answer (score 5):

You should include the image data with the email.

You can do this by encoding the image data in base64

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('logo.gif')); ?>">
```